# Query returns "LIKE" results despite not having wildcards?

Tags: mysql, sql, equality

I'm really confused here. Running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `form` = 'Depotplåster' AND `size` = 5
```

returns rows that also start with "5", despite me neither using `LIKE` nor a `%` wildcard operator. How come?

The `size` field is of type `VARCHAR`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the 5 inside single quotes?

Comment: I would guess that because you're not quoting `5` as a string (`'5'`) that you're forcing the column to be converted to an integer, and apparently `5 x 1 plåster`, when converted to an integer, is 5. I'm mildly surprised that mysql wouldn't warn you about the extra text though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because you're using comparison between numeric and varchar data. MySQL will implicitly convert your column to `double`, resulting in `5`. See this simple test data:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+-----------------+
| name            |
+-----------------+
| 5               |
| 5 and some crap |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, "good" way: compare strings:

```
mysql> select * from test where name = '5';
+------+
| name |
+------+
| 5    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And "bad" way: compare integers:

```
mysql> select * from test where name = 5;
+-----------------+
| name            |
+-----------------+
| 5               |
| 5 and some crap |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
```

-and here is your reason:

```
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                             |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5 and some crap' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, to understand, why is it so:

```
SELECT 
  CAST('5' AS DECIMAL) AS 5d, 
  CAST('5 and some crap' AS DECIMAL) AS 5sd, 
  CAST('5' AS DECIMAL) = CAST('5 and some crap' AS DECIMAL) AS areEqual;
```

Will result in:

```
+----+-----+----------+
| 5d | 5sd | areEqual |
+----+-----+----------+
|  5 |   5 |        1 |
+----+-----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-as you can see, non-significant part was just truncated (as mentioned in warning message above)

Comment: Thank you. So it was just a simple mistake from my side. Hope other people come here and learn as I did :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `form` = 'Depotplåster' AND `size` = '5'
-- this will compare the string 'size' with the string '5'


SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `form` = 'Depotplåster' AND `size` = 5
-- this will convert string 'size' to integer and then compare with the integer 5
```

The conversion of string to integer looks for ints i nthe beginning of the string, and takes the largest integer until the first non-numeric character.

```
select '5s4'=5, 's5'=5, '5'=5 -- =>1,0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `articles`
WHERE `form` = 'Depotplåster'
AND `size` = '5'
```

You should quote 5 because MySQL convert string from the table to int without quotes.